# How to make scatter plot from Pandas DataFrame using plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Following the tutorial [here](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) I wrote the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


filename = "short_rtv.pkl"
output_df = pd.read_pickle(filename)

data = px.data.output_df()
fig = px.scatter(data, x="Lat", y="Long", hover_data=["Request"])
fig.show()
```

But I receive the error

```
AttributeError: module 'plotly.express.data' has no attribute 'output_df'
```

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Get rid of the `data = px.data.output_df()` and use `fig = px.scatter(output_df, x="Lat", y="Long", hover_data=["Request"])`?

Comment: looks like another student finding same assignment challenging :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926306/plotting-latitude-and-longitude-on-scatter-plot/67926739#67926739

Comment: @RobRaymond ahaha thank you for your answer on that one, although I am not a student right now, I am researcher who very stupidly saved lat/long data as strings and couldn't figure out why it was failing ))