# Plotting latitude and longitude on scatter plot

Tags: python, plotly

I want to make a scatter plot of latlong points that are close together (i.e., in the same city).

So far I have written:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


filename = "short_rtv.pkl"
df = pd.read_pickle(filename)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="Long", y="Lat", hover_data=["Request"])
fig.write_html("plot.html")
```

but this yields me a very strange looking scatter plot:

[image]

whereas I was hoping for something more like:

[image]

This second image was generated using plotly's graph objects/map features; however, I do not want a map plot, I want a scatter plot. Is it possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- have used UK administrational areas as sample data
- it's important to set **width** and **height** to prevent *x* being stretched
- from your image it appears that **long** and **lat** columns are strings not floats

```
dfso = pd.DataFrame({"areaName": ["Aberdeen City", "Aberdeenshire", "Antrim and Newtownabbey", "Ards and North Down", "Argyll and Bute", "Blaenau Gwent", "Bridgend", "Caerphilly", "Cardiff", "Carmarthenshire", "Ceredigion", "Derby", "Devon", "Dorset", "Dumfries and Galloway", "East Sussex", "Falkirk", "Fermanagh and Omagh", "Flintshire", "Halton", "Highland", "Isle of Anglesey", "Isle of Wight", "Kingston upon Hull, City of", "Lincolnshire", "Lisburn and Castlereagh", "Merthyr Tydfil", "Mid and East Antrim", "Monmouthshire", "Moray", "Na h-Eileanan Siar", "Neath Port Talbot", "Newport", "Norfolk", "North Lincolnshire", "Orkney Islands", "Peterborough", "Portsmouth", "Powys", "Rhondda Cynon Taf", "Scottish Borders", "Shetland Islands", "Shropshire", "Somerset", "Suffolk", "Swindon", "Thurrock", "Torbay", "Torfaen", "Vale of Glamorgan", "Walsall", "West Sussex", "Windsor and Maidenhead", "Wrexham", "Armagh City, Banbridge and Craigavon", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barnet", "Barnsley", "Belfast", "Bexley", "Cambridgeshire", "Causeway Coast and Glens", "Coventry", "Cumbria", "Darlington", "Derbyshire", "Doncaster", "Dudley", "East Riding of Yorkshire", "Essex", "Fife", "Gateshead", "Gwynedd", "Hampshire", "Harrow", "Havering", "Herefordshire, County of", "Hertfordshire", "Hillingdon", "Inverclyde", "Kent", "Leicestershire", "Medway", "Mid Ulster", "Middlesbrough", "Milton Keynes", "Newry, Mourne and Down", "North Somerset", "North Yorkshire", "Northamptonshire", "Nottinghamshire", "Oxfordshire", "Pembrokeshire", "Plymouth", "Redbridge", "Redcar and Cleveland", "Rotherham", "Rutland", "Sandwell", "Sheffield", "South Lanarkshire", "Southend-on-Sea", "Staffordshire", "Sunderland", "Surrey", "Wiltshire", "Worcestershire", "Bath and North East Somerset", "Birmingham", "Bournemouth, Christchurch and Poole", "Brent", "Brighton and Hove", "Bristol, City of", "Bromley", "Buckinghamshire", "Conwy", "Cornwall and Isles of Scilly", "County Durham", "Croydon", "Denbighshire", "Derry City and Strabane", "Ealing", "East Ayrshire", "East Dunbartonshire", "Enfield", "Gloucestershire", "Greenwich", "Hackney and City of London", "Haringey", "Hartlepool", "Hounslow", "Kingston upon Thames", "Lewisham", "Merton", "Newham", "North Lanarkshire", "Perth and Kinross", "Richmond upon Thames", "Slough", "Solihull", "South Ayrshire", "South Gloucestershire", "South Tyneside", "Southampton", "St. Helens", "Stockton-on-Tees", "Stoke-on-Trent", "Sutton", "Swansea", "Telford and Wrekin", "Wakefield", "Waltham Forest", "Warrington", "Warwickshire", "West Berkshire", "West Lothian", "Westminster", "Wirral", "Wolverhampton", "York", "Angus", "Bedford", "Blackburn with Darwen", "Blackpool", "Bolton", "Bracknell Forest", "Bradford", "Bury", "Calderdale", "Camden", "Central Bedfordshire", "Cheshire East", "Cheshire West and Chester", "City of Edinburgh", "Clackmannanshire", "Dundee City", "East Lothian", "East Renfrewshire", "Glasgow City", "Hammersmith and Fulham", "Islington", "Kensington and Chelsea", "Kirklees", "Knowsley", "Lambeth", "Lancashire", "Leeds", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Luton", "Manchester", "Midlothian", "Newcastle upon Tyne", "North Ayrshire", "North East Lincolnshire", "North Tyneside", "Northumberland", "Nottingham", "Oldham", "Reading", "Renfrewshire", "Rochdale", "Salford", "Sefton", "Southwark", "Stirling", "Stockport", "Tameside", "Tower Hamlets", "Trafford", "Wandsworth", "West Dunbartonshire", "Wigan", "Wokingham"], 
                     "long": [-2.20398, -2.79208, -6.1776, -5.64568, -5.22114, -3.18592, -3.61375, -3.19753, -3.22209, -4.2111, -3.94993, -1.47189, -3.65698, -2.41467, -4.02863, 0.334559, -3.83619, -7.5271, -3.18248, -2.68853, -4.66103, -4.32298, -1.33366, -0.30382, -0.23884, -6.03545, -3.36425, -6.14645, -2.9028, -3.20202, -6.65722, -3.74638, -2.89769, 0.964714, -0.52407, -2.90025, -0.26874, -1.07006, -3.43531, -3.41359, -2.85869, -1.37344, -2.73667, -3.29595, 1.04919, -1.73367, 0.334861, -3.55523, -3.05101, -3.39801, -1.97044, -0.45933, -0.67541, -2.99203, -6.43455, 0.129479, -0.21819, -1.54925, -5.92535, 0.146212, -0.23506, -6.5996, -1.51908, -2.90213, -1.56835, -1.6021, -1.10894, -2.10171, -0.66195, 0.54106, -2.98251, -1.6868, -3.77715, -1.24735, -0.33598, 0.235368, -2.73931, -0.27699, -0.44182, -4.75387, 0.72137, -1.3779, 0.563174, -6.8889, -1.21099, -0.7407, -6.08891, -2.75438, -1.55032, -0.86668, -1.00656, -1.29146, -4.90818, -4.11297, 0.070085, -1.00608, -1.28651, -0.6263, -2.00771, -1.54254, -3.83272, 0.706923, -2.02756, -1.43344, -0.33911, -1.92661, -2.20935, -2.48654, -1.88141, -1.84807, -0.27568, -0.15079, -2.57742, 0.039246, -0.80569, -3.74646, -4.64254, -1.8405, -0.07761, -3.34761, -7.42064, -0.3141, -4.29057, -4.22417, -0.08144, -2.15235, 0.050093, -0.06045, -0.1067, -1.27018, -0.37855, -0.28367, -0.01734, -0.18868, 0.027261, -3.9514, -3.88484, -0.28914, -0.57617, -1.71558, -4.72899, -2.46922, -1.44679, -1.39952, -2.7031, -1.30664, -2.15888, -0.17226, -3.96723, -2.48941, -1.42092, -0.0188, -2.56167, -1.56874, -1.27364, -3.60909, -0.15295, -3.06701, -2.12746, -1.07375, -2.8921, -0.45463, -2.4636, -3.02199, -2.47952, -0.73363, -1.87389, -2.3088, -1.96182, -0.16291, -0.47754, -2.29299, -2.70298, -3.27826, -3.75316, -2.97095, -2.72435, -4.3606, -4.21479, -0.21735, -0.10989, -0.18977, -1.78085, -2.83297, -0.11385, -2.46091, -1.50736, -1.1304, -2.91364, -0.42319, -2.23359, -3.11738, -1.65297, -4.7246, -0.13911, -1.50923, -2.07523, -1.16667, -2.05274, -0.99071, -4.56834, -2.14784, -2.38485, -2.99177, -0.07308, -4.32595, -2.12467, -2.077, -0.03647, -2.36572, -0.20021, -4.52074, -2.57247, -0.89935], 
                     "lat": [57.166969, 57.234692, 54.693859, 54.564091, 56.28944, 51.753639, 51.5606, 51.650009, 51.502541, 51.894951, 52.297951, 52.914639, 50.725578, 50.79697, 55.09621, 50.938049, 56.000751, 54.385208, 53.21471, 53.33424, 57.586571, 53.279308, 50.671291, 53.769199, 53.111019, 54.49752, 51.748581, 54.86462, 51.778271, 57.476799, 58.199379, 51.644501, 51.58231, 52.67123, 53.58643, 58.94334, 52.59214, 50.807999, 52.34864, 51.621849, 55.525951, 60.504951, 52.62212, 51.071819, 52.253849, 51.577629, 51.509979, 50.470921, 51.69836, 51.44836, 52.60503, 50.95134, 51.480339, 53.001671, 54.3867, 51.545551, 51.611069, 53.525768, 54.59853, 51.458221, 52.349659, 55.039619, 52.41423, 54.636379, 54.535339, 53.078579, 53.52697, 52.495129, 53.881119, 51.809818, 56.231121, 54.931198, 52.89883, 51.044739, 51.594669, 51.565189, 52.081539, 51.808788, 51.53664, 55.900299, 51.192951, 52.68779, 51.44772, 54.552731, 54.54467, 52.072411, 54.149529, 51.39706, 54.093712, 52.31105, 53.128502, 51.771549, 51.855129, 50.404942, 51.58588, 54.56752, 53.395531, 52.667648, 52.514771, 53.40358, 55.60453, 51.549171, 52.909302, 54.857189, 51.268028, 51.328831, 52.212872, 51.356041, 52.484039, 50.74609, 51.564381, 50.8465, 51.471149, 51.372662, 51.769661, 53.147388, 50.450218, 54.685131, 51.365971, 53.088329, 54.80904, 51.524422, 55.496738, 55.95829, 51.648891, 51.81971, 51.46394, 51.55492, 51.587711, 54.67614, 51.462379, 51.39296, 51.442299, 51.41058, 51.53149, 55.868141, 56.575279, 51.44035, 51.503502, 52.431, 55.23008, 51.54673, 54.969879, 50.9212, 53.458618, 54.556911, 53.017071, 51.357552, 51.658058, 52.714169, 53.659222, 51.594608, 53.391628, 52.179771, 51.445591, 55.8992, 51.512211, 53.374779, 52.597881, 53.96582, 56.725182, 52.196281, 53.700802, 53.82164, 53.584492, 51.411301, 53.843819, 53.593102, 53.720482, 51.543049, 51.999031, 53.167931, 53.163361, 55.911201, 56.147839, 56.4776, 55.94207, 55.74868, 55.876492, 51.487331, 51.54546, 51.496479, 53.64233, 53.437881, 51.464451, 53.86216, 53.822731, 52.635921, 53.408298, 51.891022, 53.470089, 55.82111, 55.021011, 55.72789, 53.52327, 55.028961, 55.300369, 52.954189, 53.557678, 51.453018, 55.848621, 53.60741, 53.479271, 53.482101, 51.465939, 56.249531, 53.391159, 53.478668, 51.515541, 53.41671, 51.4524, 56.0014, 53.51445, 51.422958]})

px.scatter(dfso, x="long", y="lat", hover_name="areaName", width=400, height=400)
```

[image]